# Is it necessary to tweak settings.py in Django app in order to correctly set up SSL protection (with nginx reverse proxy + gunicorn)

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx

I have a Django app where the webserver is nginx reverse proxy + gunicorn.

**My question is:** when one installs SSL on the webserver of a Django app, is it necessary to tweak `settings.py` before https://example.com will correctly load? Or will https://example.com be accessible even *without* tweaking settings.py?

Currently, for me https://example.com just times out, and I'm trying to diagnose whether this is a problem with how I've installed SSL on the webserver, or whether it's because I haven't yet tweaked my settings.py file.

For instance, Django docs recommend setting the following in `settings.py`:

1) Setting `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` in case `https` is being *swallowed* by a proxy.

2) Setting `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` to `True` directs http traffic to https. Though this can be done more securely on the webserver.

3) Setting `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` and `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` to `True` ensures only these cookies are sent over https.

None of these settings look like a must have for https://example.com to correctly load.

---

*It turned out, the final straw was including the relevant port (i.e. port 443) in the Azure portal (where my infrastructure is hosted).*

Comment: In general you don't need to change anything to make SSL work. The suggestions above increase the security but not _must_. If it times out, most probably NginX is not listening to port 443. Post your nginx conf file to make sure.

Comment: @Selcuk: Just what I thought too. You can add this as the answer, I'll accept it and move on to diagnosing my web server. BTW in case you have any suggestion for where I can look, would love to hear from you (I set a separate question about it here:http://serverfault.com/questions/758709/getting-ssl-to-work-on-django-project)

Comment: Your config file looks fine to me. I would strip all the non-critical location directives (only leaving the proxy_pass block) to have a bare minimum .conf file and test with it.

Comment: Moreover, my DB is hosted separately on another machine. So far I've assumed that I don't have to open port 443 on that separate machine. That can't be the problem right?

Comment: No, it can't be, they are completely irrelevant. You don't also need to open port 80 on your database machine for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you don't need to change anything to make SSL work. The suggestions above increase the security but they are not musts.

If your request times out, there can be two reasons:

1. NginX is not listening to port 443. Post your `.conf` file to make sure
2. You have a firewall installed on your server which blocks incoming TCP requests to port 443.